# Why is my inner div with display:block pushed down inside a parent with display:inline?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML+CSS

```
<div>
    <div class="first">text</div>
    <div>more text</div>
</div>

div {
    display: inline;
}
.first {
    display: block;
}
```

The, somewhat surprising, result of that, is that before the `first` item, I'm getting an *empty line* (in Chrome and Firefox anyway).

I'd appreciate someone explaining to me why that happens if the first div inside an `inline` parent has `display: block;`

here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/kkozmic/fsm9D/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you should not embed block elements within inline elements. Block elements use the whole width while inline elements do not - they just use width enough to show text within them

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#block-inline

EDIT: Here's a good explanation http://skypoetsworld.blogspot.in/2008/10/dont-ever-put-block-inside-inline.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok the first item contains display: block; according to the definition a   block element is an element that takes up the full width available, and has a line break before and after it.

That's why you get a empty line before first element